# MSAL PublicClientApplicationBuilder with AzureAD external user cannot access SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

We have a Windows Application using MSAL with PublicClientApplicationBuilder to access SharePoint with the delegated permissions of the logged on user.

When our code is used with a login of a user who was invited as an external user in another AzureAD and his user is added to the members of a SharePoint site collection, we get an access token which results in HTTP 401. Using a user from the other AzureAD directly to log in does work. It is just with external user, we fail to get access.

When the user logs into SharePoint in the browser, using his external user login, he can access the other tenants SharePoint. So his external user account has permissions on that site collection, but it works only in the browser, not from our MSAL client.

Some details:

We created the app registration as multi tenant app in our AzureAD with the needed read and write permissions from the SharePoint delegated permission list.

An admin of the other AzureAD consented the delegated permissions for all users and we did the same in our AzureAD. So no matter which user tries to login and use the app will find consented permissions.

We use this code to get a public client app:

```
var clientAppId = "our-app-clientID";
var redirectUri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient";

_clientApp = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientAppId)
.WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)
.WithLogging(Log, LogLevel.Verbose, false)
// .WithTenantId("we tried our and the other tenants ID")
.Build();
```

The commented line .WithTenantId was just added while we tried to find a solution.

We can see that it makes a difference for the token content. Without that line or with our tenantId we see the users "oid" is the objectId from the user in our AzureAD.

When we use the tenantId of the other AzureAD, we get the oid of the external user object in that other AzureAD.

So we had hopes that the latter call would succeed, but it fails as well, this time with HTTP 403. So the user token seems to get a bit further, but still not to the SharePoint site collection.

Any idea if this scenario is possible?

Would be nice, if possible and best if we would not have to call WithTenantId because otherwise we would some need to lookup the correct tenantId on the client machine - not sure where to get it from, except asking an admin from the other tenant and putting the value in some app config file or the Windows registry.

Answer (score 0):

•   The issue most probably according to your description suggests that the scopes might not be added correctly to the **‘Sharepoint API’** because since you are accessing the sharepoint site from a public client using MSAL authentication, the `scopes/permissions` to access the sharepoint site from a public client in Azure AD needs to be added and extended to service the requests from external user accounts also.

To do so, you need to `add scopes/permissions to Sharepoint API` through the Azure portal as when you are calling SharePoint APIs outside of the Microsoft Graph, you call **‘/_api/web/lists’** and it will retrieve all the lists. Thus, if your public client app performs this action using the Microsoft Graph API permissions then you will get an access denied error message as you are encountering HTTP 403 error.

•   Thus, in your case, to access the sharepoint sites, you will need to add the scopes **‘AllSites.Read’** and **‘Sites.ReadWrite.All’** to the Sharepoint API for your public client app as the scope for **‘Sites.Read’** in the Microsoft Graph API isn’t enough for it. Also, ensure to add the `‘https://<domain>.sharepoint.com/AllSites.Write’` and `‘https://<yoursite>.sharepoint.com/Sites.ReadWrite.All’` scopes also to the Sharepoint API for that public client app.

[image: Sharepoint API permissions]
[image: Sharepoint API site scopes]

To access the Sharepoint API through public client, you use **AAD auth** for which Microsoft recommends **using a certificate rather than a secret**. For more information regarding this, kindly use the below documentation link: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-authentication-flows#client-credentials

•   Also, ensure that ***‘https://microsoft.sharepoint-df.com/Sites.Search.All’*** and ***‘https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com/Sites.Search.All’*** are also added as scope in your application as Sharepoint online site might reject the token because of invalid audience.

For more information regarding the scope modification, kindly refer the below link for more details: -

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/400

Comment: The delegate SharePoint permission AllSites.FullControl is consented and used in the scopes param. When we look at the token with jwt.ms we see this line:


 "scp": "AllSites.FullControl MyFiles.Write TermStore.ReadWrite.All User.Read.All"


So I think we use the correct scopes.


We want to use delegated rights from the logged on user, to act as the user from his Windows Client, therefore the public client. Not app rights, where we would need a confidential client with a certificate or secret.

Comment: You last link points to a thread, where one user says, guest accounts cannot access the Graph Api for SharePoint, not sure if that would be an issue for CSOM requests as well? https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/400#issuecomment-459891095

Comment: I would suggest you to please refer this SO thread's answer and discussions for more details regarding your query and issue : - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72187812/access-to-sharepoint-online-from-client-app

Comment: We use the same technique to add the bearer token, as described in that article. That is not the problem. It is working for AAD users of that tenant. It is not working for invited external AAD users. So I think my question and the other SO thread you pointed to, are unrelated and different problems. Our issue is only related to external AAD users, which can't access SharePoint Online when using MSAL and a PublicClientApplicationBuilder.