# Access to Sharepoint Online from Client App

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, sharepoint-online, .net-6.0, azure-ad-graph-api, csom

Recently I came up with an issue that I have a .NET Web API which needs to connect to SharePoint Online. In the Azure AD, I have provided all permission to the AppId  "AllSites.Manage.All", AllSites.Read.All etc. I used CSOM library to pass the token to the sharepoint. But once I am trying to execute query on the clientcontext received, It is throwing 401 UnAuthorized error

```
     private async Task<ClientContext> GetClientContextWithAccessToken1(string targetUrl)
    {
        var accessToken = await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(new string[] {"Files.ReadWrite.All", "Sites.Manage.All", "AllSites.Read"});
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync($"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me");
        if(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
        using(ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(targetUrl))
        {
            clientContext.ExecutingWebRequest +=
                delegate (object oSender, WebRequestEventArgs webRequestEventArgs)
                {
                    webRequestEventArgs.WebRequestExecutor.RequestHeaders["Authorization"] =
                        "Bearer " + accessToken;
                };
            return clientContext;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide decoded token details masking sensitive info to troubleshoot further to check other cases of error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the request to query https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me , one of the below permissions is required to be granted consent from admin. like Directory.Read.All , User.Read.All ...

[image]

Also please make sure to add `Sites.Read.All`  or `Sites.ReadWrite.All`  Application permission in your registrated AAD Application and do admin consent for it before you getting token to access sharepoint sites.
[image]

If you're using v2 endpoint, please go to below URL in your internet browser to do admin grant:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{yourtenant}/adminconsent?client_id={ applicationid /clientId }&state=123&redirect_uri={redirect uri of your app}
```

and sign in with Global administrator account and accept this permission.

Reference:
[azure-app-cannot-access-sharepoint-online-sites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/131535/azure-app-cannot-access-sharepoint-online-sites-us.html?msclkid=3403f63cd09a11ec97e20833e1dd555e)

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling Microsoft Graph API endpoints you should avoid using csom.

`AllSites.Manage.All`, `AllSites.Read.All` etc. permissions are related to SharePoint and CSOM and they will not work for Graph API endpoints.

For Graph API you need to acquire different [token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/auth-concepts) or better option is to use [Microsoft Graph Client Library for .NET](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet) in your case.